# Cordova iOS RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm having a recurring error in cordova with iOS trying to save images to disk.

I'm using Corodova 2.9 with iOS 6/7

the error is the following:

```
[Error] RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
encodeArrayBufferAs8bitString (cordova.js, line 845)
encodeArrayBufferAsBase64 (cordova.js, line 848)
(anonymous function) (cordova.js, line 854)
forEach
massageArgsJsToNative (cordova.js, line 850)
iOSExec (cordova.js, line 941)
write (cordova.js, line 3090)
onload (cordova.js, line 3064)
```

this is the function that is being referenced.

```
function massageArgsJsToNative(args) {
if (!args || utils.typeName(args) != 'Array') {
   return args;
}
var ret = [];
var encodeArrayBufferAs8bitString = function(ab) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(ab)); //Line 845
};
var encodeArrayBufferAsBase64 = function(ab) {
    return window.btoa(encodeArrayBufferAs8bitString(ab));
};
args.forEach(function(arg, i) {
    if (utils.typeName(arg) == 'ArrayBuffer') {
        ret.push({
            'CDVType': 'ArrayBuffer',
            'data': encodeArrayBufferAsBase64(arg)
        });
    } else {
        ret.push(arg);
    }
});
return ret;
}
```

This is my function that calls the writer

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("get", url, true );
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
oReq.onload = function ( oEvent )
{
    var url_arr = url.split(".");
    var blob = new Blob([oReq.response], {type: "image/" + url_arr[url_arr.length - 1]});
    console.log(blob.size,blob.type);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    fileSystem.root.getFile(
        "../Library/Caches/" + url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''),
        {create: true},
        function (fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(function (writer) {

                writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                    console.log("wrote file " + url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''));
                    new_url = "../../Library/Caches/" + url.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
                    saveMedia(new_url);

                };

                writer.write(blob);
            },
            function fail(error) {
                console.log("fileEntry.createWriter", JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        },
        function fail(error) {
            console.log("fileSystem.root.getFile", JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    );
};
oReq.send(null);
```

What is most puzzling is that sometimes this happens and sometimes it doesn't. It's not a constant error.

Any advice or idea will be very appreciated!

Comment: Error: have a task running infinite and not finish

Comment: @HanhLe thx for your reply, I'm sorry I've just seen this comment.

Comment: @HanhLe What do you meen with running infinit? do you see anything in the code that might do that?